# Can anyone help me pass this data? ;)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, audio, dynamic

I am new to development. There of course are a few fundamentals I am struggling with.  If anyone could help me and give a little explanation I would greatly appreciate it.

I am creating a synth using the tone.js library. I understand how to create the synth passing it one "Instrument", but I am having an issue doing it dynamically and I am digging myself a hole.

Here's the code:

```js
//instruments 
const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
const amSynth = new Tone.AMSynth().toDestination();
const duoSynth = new Tone.DuoSynth().toDestination();
const fmSynth = new Tone.FMSynth().toDestination();
const membraneSynth = new Tone.MembraneSynth().toDestination();
const metalSynth = new Tone.MetalSynth().toDestination();
const monoSynth = new Tone.MonoSynth({
  oscillator: {
    type: "square"
  },
  envelope: {
    attack: 0.1
  }
}).toDestination();
const noiseSynth = new Tone.NoiseSynth().toDestination();
const pluckSynth = new Tone.PluckSynth().toDestination();
const polySynth = new Tone.PolySynth().toDestination();
const sampler = new Tone.Sampler({
  urls: {
    A1: "A1.mp3",
    A2: "A2.mp3",
  },
  baseUrl: "https://tonejs.github.io/audio/casio/",
  onload: () => {
    sampler.triggerAttackRelease(["C1", "E1", "G1", "B1"], 0.5);
  }
}).toDestination();

//effects 
const distortion = new Tone.Distortion(0.4).toDestination();
const vibrato = new Tone.Vibrato(0.4).toDestination();
const pingPong = new Tone.PingPongDelay("4n", 0.2).toDestination()
const autoWah = new Tone.AutoWah(50, 6, -30).toDestination();
const cheby = new Tone.Chebyshev(50).toDestination();
const autoFilter = new Tone.AutoFilter("4n").toDestination()
const autoPanner = new Tone.AutoPanner("4n").toDestination();
const crusher = new Tone.BitCrusher(4).toDestination();
const chorus = new Tone.Chorus(4, 2.5, 0.5).toDestination();
const feedbackDelay = new Tone.FeedbackDelay("8n", 0.5).toDestination();
const freeverb = new Tone.Freeverb().toDestination();
freeverb.dampening = 1000;
const shift = new Tone.FrequencyShifter(42).toDestination();
const reverb = new Tone.JCReverb(0.4).toDestination();
const phaser = new Tone.Phaser({
  frequency: 15,
  octaves: 5,
  baseFrequency: 1000
}).toDestination();
const tremolo = new Tone.Tremolo(9, 0.75).toDestination();


//array of notes --- we add the sharps in the function 
var notes = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']
var html = '';

for (var octave = 0; octave < 2; octave++) {


  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    var hasSharp = true;
    var note = notes[i]

    if (note == 'E' || note == 'B')
      hasSharp = false;

    //white keys with one octive
    html += `<div class='whitenote play' onmousedown='noteDown(this)' data-note='${note + (octave + 4)}'>`;

    //black keys with one octive
    if (hasSharp) {
      html += `<div class='blacknote play' onmousedown='noteDown(this)' data-note='${note + '#' + (octave + 4)}'></div>`;
    }

    html += '</div>'
  }

}
$('container').innerHTML = html;

$(".play").click(function(elem) {
  var note = elem.dataset.note;
  var synth = getSynth(elem.data("synth"));
  synth.connect(phaser);
  synth.connect(autoWah);
  synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, "16n");
  event.stopPropagation();
});


function getSynth(name) {
  switch (name) {
    case "Synth":
      return synth;
    case "AM":
      return amSynth;
    case "Duo":
      return duoSynth;
    case "FM":
      return fmSynth;
    case "Membrane":
      return membraneSynth;
    case "Metal":
      return metalSynth;
    case "Mono":
      return monoSynth;
    case "Noise":
      return noiseSynth;
    case "Pluck":
      return pluckSynth;
    case "Poly":
      return polySynth;
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  white-space: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.whitenote {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.blacknote {
  position: absolute;
  height: 65%;
  width: 55%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #777;
  left: 68%;
}

.instrument-button {
  background: orangered;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.effect-button {
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.effect-button-padding {
  padding-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.8.26/Tone.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.8.26/Tone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src='node_modules\tone\build\Tone.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.8.26/Tone.js.map'></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body style="align-items: center;">
  <div>
    <h1>Synth AF</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Intruments</h4>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="Synth" id="synth-button">Synth</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="AM" id="amSynth-button">AM</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="Duo" id="duoSynth-button">Duo</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="FM" id="fmSynth-button">FM</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="Membrane" id="membraneSynth-button">Drums</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="Metal" id="metalSynth-button">Metal</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="Mono" id="monoSynth-button">Mono</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="Noise" id="noiseSynth-button">Noise</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="Pluck" id="pluckSynth-button">Plucky</button>
    <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth="Poly" id="polySynth-button">Poly</button>
  </div>
  <div class="effect-button-padding">
    <h4>Effects</h4>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="distortion-button">Distortion</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="vibrato-button">Vibrato</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="pingPong-button">PingPong</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="autoWah-button">Wah</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="crusher-button">BitCrusher</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="phaser-button">Phaser</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="reverb-button">Reverb</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="autoFilter-button">Auto Filter</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="feedbackDelay-button">Feedback</button>
    <button class='btn effect-button' id="cheby-button">Chebyshev</button>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="container">

  </div>
  
  </body> 
 </html>
```

Here is the UI. (Haven't designed it yet...don't judge)
[UI Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRYx2.png)

The idea is to use one of the new instruments created in the one constants by passing it through a button click, to a switch statement and then to the output.  I apologize if I didn't explain anything clearly or used the wrong terminology.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Thank you for reading,
FandopTheNoob

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, in the future when adding a snippit of code, make sure to properly add the libraries needed to your code in order for your snippit to parse the code properly. The reason for adding a snippit is so you can recreate the issue you are outlining in your question. I added the tone js CDN as yours was linked locally to your machine. I also added JQuery and placed the proper code within the proper sections of the snippit so it would parse properly for you. Good luck with your issue and again welcome to Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate the help @dale landry. I couldn't get the keys to show in separate files. I am sure that I would learn much more from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// this will be the "state" of the synthesiser
const synthSetup = {
  instrument: "",
  effects: [],
}

// this is the list of instruments
const instruments = [{
    synth: "Synth",
    id: "synth-button",
    text: "Synth",
    tone: new Tone.Synth().toDestination(),
  },
  {
    synth: "AM",
    id: "amSynth-button",
    text: "AM",
    tone: new Tone.AMSynth().toDestination(),
  },
]

// this is the list of effects
const effects = [{
    id: "distortion-button",
    text: "Distortion",
    tone: new Tone.Distortion(0.4).toDestination(),
  },
  {
    id: "vibrator-button",
    text: "Vibrato",
    tone: new Tone.Vibrato(0.4).toDestination(),
  },
]

// setting up the instruments & effects buttons
const instrumentsHtml = (instruments) => {
  return instruments.map(({
    synth,
    id,
    text
  }) => {
    return `
      <button class="btn instrument-button" data-synth=${synth} id="${id}">${text}</button>
    `
  }).join('')
}

const effectsHtml = (effects) => {
  return effects.map(({
    id,
    text
  }) => {
    return `
      <button class="btn effect-button" id="${id}">${text}</button>
    `
  }).join('')
}

const instrumentsContainer = document.getElementById("btn-group-instruments")
instrumentsContainer.innerHTML = instrumentsHtml(instruments)

const effectsContainer = document.getElementById("btn-group-effects")
effectsContainer.innerHTML = effectsHtml(effects)

// setting up click handlers on the instruments & effects buttons
$("body").on("click", ".instrument-button", function() {
  // setting up synthSetup.instrument:
  synthSetup.instrument = $(this).data("synth")
})

$("body").on("click", ".effect-button", function() {
  // setting up synthSetup.effects:
  synthSetup.effects = [...new Set([...synthSetup.effects, $(this).attr("id")])]
})

//array of notes --- we add the sharps in the function
var notes = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']
var html = '';

for (var octave = 0; octave < 2; octave++) {


  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    var hasSharp = true;
    var note = notes[i]

    if (note == 'E' || note == 'B')
      hasSharp = false;

    //white keys with one octave
    html += `<div class='whitenote play' data-note='${note + (octave + 4)}'>`;

    //black keys with one octave
    if (hasSharp) {
      html += `<div class='blacknote play' data-note='${note + '#' + (octave + 4)}'></div>`;
    }

    html += '</div>'
  }

}
const container = document.getElementById("container")
container.innerHTML = html;

$("body").on("click", ".play", function() {
  if (!synthSetup.instrument) {
    alert("Choose an instrument first!")
  } else {
    const {
      tone: synth
    } = instruments.find(({
      synth
    }) => synth === synthSetup.instrument)
    const note = $(this).data("note")

    // connecting the effects
    synthSetup.effects.forEach(e => {
      const effect = effects.find(({
        id
      }) => e)
      synth.connect(effect.tone)
    })

    const now = Tone.now()
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, "2n", now)
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  white-space: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.whitenote {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.blacknote {
  position: absolute;
  height: 65%;
  width: 55%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #777;
  left: 68%;
}

.instrument-button {
  background: orangered;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.effect-button {
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.effect-button-padding {
  padding-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.8.26/Tone.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.8.26/Tone.js.map'></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <h1>Synth AF</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Intruments</h4>
  <div id="btn-group-instruments"></div>
</div>
<div class="effect-button-padding">
  <h4>Effects</h4>
  <div id="btn-group-effects"></div>
</div>
<div class="" id="container">

</div>
```

So, here's the next step for this synthesizer:

- the current state of the synthesizer is kept in `synthSetup`
- the instruments are stored as an array of objects
- the effects are stored as an array of objects
- instruments & effects are put to the DOM dynamically
- on clicking any white or black button the `synthSetup` (state) is read & the note is played (chosen instrument & the list of effects)

Issues:

- you cannot remove an effect from the list of effects (it could be handled in the click handler of the effect buttons)

Comment: thank you so much. I will get back to you on how this is working

Comment: Thank you so  much man, this is super helpful. I think I need to tackle creating the server for this node project and then I can test. 

I will update

Comment: @FandopTheNoob I'm glad that I could help. It's always helpful to store data in a format that's easy to iterate over (arrays, objects, etc.) - computers are really good at running through a list of things :)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at synth.js:60`

on this line 

`const instrumentsContainer = document.getElementById("btn-group-instruments")
instrumentsContainer.innerHTML = instrumentsHtml(instruments)
`

Comment: Also the black notes aren't playing sharps anymore.  It is the previous white notes pitch now.

Comment: could it be because it isnt sure if the user is pressing the white or black key? 

Both have the class of play...
` $("body").on("click", ".play", function() {`

then the onclick calls that

Comment: @FandopTheNoob probably you are right - the snippet I provided mainly focuses on HOW you set up the synthesizer data, not how you use the app. It's easier to update the code this way, if something doesn't work out exactly as you wanted.

Comment: Muka, do you have time to glance at my newest question